# org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: (foo)

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I have two classes being managed by Hibernate, `ClassA` and `ClassB`. `ClassA` has a reference to `ClassB`. According to the documentation Hibernate should be able to get the type through reflection. I can't understand why this doesn't work. Am I missing something really fundamental here?

This is `ClassA` marked with the `@Entity` annotation and holding a reference to `ClassB`.

```
package dom;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class ClassA {

    private ClassB classB;

    private long id;        

    public ClassA() {};

    public ClassB getClassB() {
        return classB;
    }

    public void setClassB(ClassB classB) {
        this.classB = classB;
    }

    @Id
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   

}
```

This is `ClassB` marked with the `@Enity` annotation.

```
package dom;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class ClassB {

    private long id;

    @Id
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: dom.ClassB, at table: ClassA, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(classB)]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:316)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:294)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:238)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:469)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1294)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1742)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1788)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:247)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:373)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:358)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
```

Comment: Annotate your `ClassB` in your `ClassA` with @Column

Comment: Please specify the relation between the 2 entities, one to many, many to many, or one to one

Comment: @Arpit Your comment is incorrect. This question is about a relationship between two entities, which `@Column` does not mean.

Comment: Yes @Magnilex, you are correct, I thought about Column should work as in post nothing is mentioned about relationship between two entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to annotate the field with a `@OneToOne` (assuming it isn't a `@ManyToOne`, i.e. many `ClassB` can contain many `ClassA`'s) annotation:

```
@OneToOne
private ClassB classB;
```

This should be the minimum code needed to properly add the relation between the entities.

Comment: My real code had a ClassC that has a collection of ClassA which has a reference to ClassB that was marked with @ManyToOne, which wasn't working. Now it is.